Duplicate execution in terminal
Every time I press F5 on the keyboard to execute my code through the terminal, the first time it executes normally, but the second time it happens that ^C appears, an empty execution and then it executes normally as shown in the printout.
I've already done several procedures to disable all vscode extensions, reinstalled several times and still the problem persists.

Is your script still running when you try it again?  If so, this is normal behavior.  It will kill the first one before running it again.  This has nothing to do with Python.  I tagged vscode, which is what this is actually about.

That did happen to me, but you could try running in a different way in VS Code. You can try clicking the Run and Debug button every time you want to run, or you can ignore the ^C. As I told you, that did happen to me. It seems like the ^C isn't going to matter much, it still runs perfectly. If you really want to get rid of the ^C, maybe you can contact Microsoft for help. I hope this helps!
